# What does reverence mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Their two children were like all agreeable children, and Lucile and Bellard **went through the reverence**, anxiety, and joy of their upbringing. And whether the moment yielded a torn frock or a hurt knee, croup or a moral crisis, Lucile seemed to put the event in its place and not to be overwhelmed by it.

Dose it mean that sometimes they experienced (felt) great admiration for having children?

This passage is from the short story named: The woman by Zona Gale

Comment: Have you looked up "go through" in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes I looked up " go through" in the dictionary but I dont  get its meanig in this context and with "reverence".

Comment: OK, include what you found in your question then.

Comment: I believe it means they took their role as parents very seriously.

Answer (score -1):

**Lucile and Bellard went through the reverence ...**

**go through** [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/go-through)

> [transitive] [go through something] to experience something difficult
>   or unpleasant

**reverence**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/reverence)

> a feeling of profound respect for someone or something

Lucile and Bellard went through (experienced the difficulties of parenthood) the reverence (awe and respect of parenthood) ...

> Dose it mean that sometimes they experienced (felt) great admiration
>   for having children?

No, that would be the **joy**.  The **difficulties** they experienced as parents commanded/elicited the unexpected respect (**reverence**) of what it means to be a parent.

Comment: Wouldn't the difficulties be the cause of the anxiety? Maybe it means that other people now showed them respect.